# my code is not working, tried every manner for urllib package?

Tags: python-3.x

```
import re
>>> import urllib.request
>>> url="https://www.google.com/search?q=googlestock"
>>> print(url)
https://www.google.com/search?q=googlestock
>>> data=urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
```

I get an error however the url works fine when opened manually. error is

```
     File "<pyshell#4>", line 1, in <module>
       data=urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
     File "C:\Users\SHARM\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 222, in urlopen
       return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
     File "C:\Users\SHARM\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 531, in open
       response = meth(req, response)
     File "C:\Users\SHARM\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 641, in http_response
       'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
     File "C:\Users\SHARM\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 569, in error
       return self._call_chain(*args)
     File "C:\Users\SHARM\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 503, in _call_chain
       result = func(*args)
     File "C:\Users\SHARM\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 649, in http_error_default
       raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
   urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
```

Comment: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden means forbidden; as to why, I'm not sure. If you try a different URL, it should work.

Comment: I think I have answered your problem in the answer below. Let me know if it worked for you or not.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do web scraping from google, you can use the "google" library.
On your command prompt, pip install google (it is literally "pip install google").
Then, just try something like that:

```
from googlesearch import search 
for s in search("googlestock"): 
    print(s)
```

This will print all of the results from google search "googlestock". Here to learn more about this library: https://pypi.org/project/google/

I hope it helps,
BR

Comment: Awesome! Could you validate my answer?